# Kafka producer and consumer motrics/monitoring

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to setup a Kafka monitoring dashboard (based on the app logs) to show the consumer lag for the given topic. I am looking for the consumer lag for following scenarios:

1. Producer is publishing to the topic when there are no active consumers - in this case the latest offset would be considered as the consumer lag
2. Producer is publishing to the topic and there are active consumers - find the lag for each consumer

I followed this article which does something similar to my requirements https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-lag but for creating AdminClient as per this article, I need to have access to the make Zookeeper configs which is currently not possible.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Since you tagged [tag:spring-kafka], have you looked here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer-native - metrics (including lags, etc) are maintained by Micrometer which can be consumed by graphana etc.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell I am using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory (spring-kafka 2.2.7.RELEASE) and do not see an option to add the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

**Grafana**

The following Grafana Dashboards are usefulfor proper Kafka monitoring

- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7589
- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/721

You can follow this [blog](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2021/07/kafka-cluster-monitoring-with.html) for set up

**Strimzi**

If you provision your Kafka cluster with [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/), it will automatically provide great dashboards.

**Datadog**

You can also use the [datadog kafka dashboard](https://www.datadoghq.com/dashboards/kafka-dashboard/) for in depth monitoring of kafka cluster

Answer (score 0):

> I am using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory (spring-kafka 2.2.7.RELEASE)

2.2.x has been out of support for several years...

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

The micrometer listeners were added in 2.5.